# user prompt in jade

Tags: javascript, pug

Working through 'Node.js in 24 Hours'.  In Chapter 6 there are some Jade examples, 05 & 06.  I've tried combining them by using prompt() to get the user to set a condition.  The code below shows what I've done.  The prompt script doesn't change the variable 'raining'.  What am I doing wrong?

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  - raining = false

  script
    raining = prompt('Raining? (true/false)')

  - if (raining)
      p It is raining.  Take an umbrella!

  - else
      p No rain. Take the bike.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing server side js with client side. Inside script tag in this case you should write client side js:

```
p(id="txtRain")

script
    var raining = confirm('Raining?')
    var txtRain = document.getElementById('txtRain');

    if (raining)
       txtRain.innerHTML = 'It is raining.  Take an umbrella.';
    else
       txtRain.innerHTML = 'No rain. Take the bike.';
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code as you suggested with success.  I spent quite a while trying to figure this out (books and online).  Besides 'stack', where would I have found the sort of info you provided?

Comment: there was nothing technology-specific in your question, you just have to diferentiate what is client side script and server side script. server script is rendered on server side and user sees result, farther interaction should be done using client side script. Sometimes it's confusing because of same languages used on both sides :)